# Validation problem if an input is empty or not with React and React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs

I am working with React and React Bootstrap.  I need to apply a class to an input when the input value is empty and apply other class when the input value is filled.

I have the next code:

```
            <FormGroup>
             <ControlLabel>Username</ControlLabel>
             <FormControl className={this.value==""?"empty":"no-empty")} type="text" value="" />
            </FormGroup>
```

My problem is that the className is always "no-empty".  If the value="" the className is "no-empty" and if the value="xyz" the className is "no-empty".

I don't know if it's related but when I apply input:valid and input:invalid to an input in react looks as all the inputs were like valid.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `this.value` is wrong - most likely you need either `this.state.value` or `this.props.value`

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaanks a lot.  This works for me.  You are right, because the value by default is not defined or empty, instead, the value is sent by props and returned by props to put the value.  

I am going to put the answer below.  Let me know if you have other solution.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are still investing time into learning JS, so let me point you to [**Operator Precedence**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Your own answer contains `this.props.username==""||undefined?"empty":"no-empty")`  (at the time of writing) - let's ignore the syntax error (unmatched `)`) and analyze the operators:

- `… ? … : …` is a *Conditional* with precedence 4
- `… || …` is a *Logical OR* with precedence 5
- `… == …` is an *Equality* with precedence 10

...that means `this.props.username==""` will be evaluated **before** the `||` part, so either `false||undefined` or `true` (see also [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)).

IMHO, the best (most readable) code for checking empty values in cases like this is simply checking whether `this.props.username` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/truthy) (anything else than `""`, `undefined`, `null`, `false` or `0`):

```
className={this.props.username ? "no-empty" : "empty"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this code worked for me:

```
<FormGroup>
    <ControlLabel>Username</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl className={this.props.username==""||undefined?"empty":"no-empty")} type="text" value="" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'username')} />
</FormGroup>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try rewrite your code in next way:

```
        <FormGroup>
     <ControlLabel>Username</ControlLabel>
     <FormControl className={this.value==!!(this.value)?"empty":"no-empty")} type="text" value="" />
    </FormGroup>
```

Comment: It can not be because the value is specific to the component and is not detected. The value is sent by props, it is received again by props and must be validated by props.